# Why is it faster to put an empty src attribute than not putting any?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working in local with Bootstrap, jQuery and HTML. When you click in a `button` you get a data-url which gets put into an iframe video. If you put an empty `src=""`, it is so much faster than not putting anything. Why is that? Apparently it looks like it doesn't matter.

Example:

```
<script>
var youtube = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"
    $("button[data-url]").click(function() {
      var code = $(this).data("url")
      var video = youtube + code
      $("iframe").attr("src", video)
    })
</script>

<button type="button" data-url="WhateverCode1">Video 1</button>
<button type="button" data-url="WhateverCode2">Video 2</button>

<!--With src="" is so much faster -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src=""></iframe>
</div>

<!-- Than no src -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you benchmark your difference ?

Comment: Because in the first case you are assigning a value to an attribute, whereas in the second case you are trying to assign a value to an attribute that doesn't exist hence it needs to be created first and then can be assigned a value.

Comment: I don't see any difference on chrome

Comment: Which browser are you using that exhibits the behavior? Do you have third-party plugins/extensions/theme installed and have you tried to disable all (factory defaults)? Certain themes and plugins can drastically alter the behavior and performance of the browser, which may make your issue unique to your environment.

Comment: How much is "so much"?

Comment: Is it just because you are loading two videos at the same time.  The first one loads first, the second one loads second?

Comment: @Editer, that was a very bad edit...

Comment: changing the codes has no impact on the video failing to load, and making the demo code runnable is not a bad edit..

Comment: I dont have any extensions/plugins, I tested in all browers, and the difference is like 2 seconds. @BuhBuh Im not obviusly trying load 2 videos at the same time, is it just the example to show you what Im saying with src

Comment: I've tested in Chrome + Ubuntu and I'm seeing at most 100ms difference between loading (or rather, failing to load) the videos using the two buttons.

Comment: I want to underline that Im using bootstrap, the iframe is inside bootstrap modal

Comment: Maybe you could improve that snippet to show what you are talking about?  Or make a JSFiddle?  At the moment I don't think anyone knows what you have done.

Comment: @BuhBuh Even I cant reproduce the performance issue in the snippet? If can it helps people to understand the question I can edit it

Answer (score 1):

It's not matter of the setting `src`, when you click button it's set the `src` value or create the `src` attribute with it's value to it's DOM at the same time.

**HTML render/populate all it's DOM in procedural way(top to bottom), So the first one load first, then the second one & so on.**